# Anchor UI editing in GeoNetwork 3.12.9

Tags: geonetwork, link

I'm working with GeoNetwork 3.12.9 and I want to add an Anchor by editor interface to a specific metadata attribute (getting as a result something similar to the "screen_mod_3"), but it seems it's not possible. The only way to do it, seems to be by editing corresponding xml as you can see in "screen_mod_2". Is there a way to add an Anchor to an attribute by editor interface (starting from a situation as shown in screen_mod_1?

[image][image]
[image]

Comment: What schema plugin and editor view are you using?